# Play Framework 1.4 staticDir routes

Tags: java, playframework-1.x

I need to save amount of images sent by users in a specific directory, 
then render this images

I'm trying to use the staticDir routes, like this:

```
GET     /test/*                                staticDir:/var/www/images
```

but when I access the url http://localhost:9000/test/test.png the response is 'not found' 'the file /var/www/images/test.png does not exist'

but the file exists in this path

somebody knows what is wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play's staticDir can only route to dir under the project root. `/var/www/images` looks like a system level path. You can probably set a symbol link from there to an image folder inside your project home